# Sequential square plane-tiling patches

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, tiling, open-problem

Using squares of size $1$ to $n$, make a patch that can tile the plane.  Solutions for $n=2, 3, 4, 5$ are easy to find.

Example for 6: 
[image: patch 6]

Example for 7: 
[image: patch 7]

Example for 8: 
[image: patch 8]

Example for 9: 
[image: patch 9]

I haven't found a solution for 10 yet.  This one lacks the unit square: 
[image: almost patch 10]

Is there a shape made from squares of size $1$ to $10$ that can tile the plane? Are there solutions for higher $n$? For $n$ that admit solutions, how many basic solutions are there?